# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I've installed UBUNTU 12.04 on my laptop & when I plug-in the Ethernet cable, it says "Disconnected"

Please advise on me this

```
PC Info:
HP Pavilion ze4600
Previously- Windows XP Pro
Now- Ubuntu 12.04
```

Comment: Can you provide any information on what type of network adaptor you have?

Comment: **Step 1)** examine the connector and look for bent pins. **Step 2)** Try replacing the CAT-5 cable. **Step 3)** Add what you've tried in order to fix the problem to your question. **Step 4)** Respond to requests for information to keep your question active and reach a solution. Repeat Step 3 and 4 as necessary. ;-)

Comment: Post results of `sudo lshw -c network`

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet from Broadband or Wifi:

Install the ethernet drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.8.0-42-generic
```

Then reboot.

Comment: K. So I don't know how to reply so I am doing this. (New)

Comment: It says 'E: unable to locate package'

Comment: Edited the answer. try now

Comment: How can the OP download anything when he/she don't have access to the internet? Could you explain more in-detail why the OP needs to install the generic linux image & so... etc?